# Writing with the new Windows 10 API

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

With Windows 10 Universal application I am trying to recreate a server application that will manage multiple component like a web site. The application would create/manage a ASP.net Web API, it would also manage the database that user currently run on their own machine. With windows 10 new API would the technology allow my application to write into any folder of my choice, if not is there limitation.

The application would be written using C#/XAML. What I am trying to say is i am feeling under the impression that I am force to write an application and limited to where I want to write a file under Application install directory, or Application data locations. but is there a way for to go into an other project where the ASP.net WEB API would exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apps can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can
>   also access additional locations through the file picker, or by
>   declaring capabilities.

Based on my understanding, this is a design for restrict permission purpose and the end-user have the full-control rather than the app.

In Windows 8.0/8.1, you can workaround it by using [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx). The basic idea is that: run the broker process in middle integrity so that it can have access to other locations, the app using IPC to communicate with the broker process.

As a workaround in Windows 10, you can also write the broker service and the App can use TCP or HTTP to communicate with the broker service.